# Объясните расстановку знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Месяц взошел наконец; я его не сразу заметил, так он был мал и узок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Месяц взошел наконец; я его не тотчас заметил: так он был мал и узок.*** (Тургенев. "Записки охотника")

В предложении 3 простых предложения, но 2 части. Первая часть ***Месяц взошел наконец...*** имеет интонацию завершённого предложения, поэтому после неё ставим не запятую, а точку с запятой.

Вторая часть - бессоюзное сложное предложение, в котором выражены причинные отношения: предложение  ***...так он был мал и узок*** указывает на причину того, о чём говорится в предложении ***...я его не тотчас заметил***. Поэтому ставим двоеточие.

Все части связаны бессоюзной интонационной связью.